# How to change primvue component font family, font size and fontweight

Tags: vuejs3, vite, primevue

I have vue3 composition api and primevue. I need to change a specific component's family, size and weight. I have spent over a day and cannot find this information. Specifically I need a dropdown changed to font family Lato, font weight: bold, and font size 1.2vw

I would like an example or point to clear documentation on how to achieve this.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can override classes style like:

```css
.p-dropdown-label,
.p-dropdown-item {
  font-family: Lato; // add !important if not applied
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
}
```

Check list of classes [list](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/showcase/#/dropdown)

**UPDATE**

```css
::v-global(.p-dropdown-label),
::v-global(.p-dropdown-item) {
  font-family: Lato !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  font-size: 1.2vw !important;
}
```

**UPDATE 2** using slots

Example:

```js
<template>
  <Dropdown
    v-model="selectedCity"
    :options="cities"
    optionLabel="name"
    placeholder="Select a City"
  >
    <template #value="{ value, placeholder }">
      <span class="p-dropdown-label__custom">{{
        value ? value.name : placeholder
      }}</span>
    </template>
    <template #option="{ option }">
      <span class="p-dropdown-item__custom">{{ option.name }}</span>
    </template>
  </Dropdown>
</template>

<script>
import Dropdown from "primevue/dropdown/sfc";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Dropdown,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selectedCity: null,
      cities: [
        { name: "New York", code: "NY" },
        { name: "Rome", code: "RM" },
        { name: "London", code: "LDN" },
        { name: "Istanbul", code: "IST" },
        { name: "Paris", code: "PRS" },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.p-dropdown-label__custom,
.p-dropdown-item__custom {
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
}
</style>
```

Comment: No changes. Seems to be ignored.

<style lang="scss" scoped>

.p-dropdown-label,
.p-dropdown-item {
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
}

</style>
<DropDown
                  v-model="numberOfPersons"
                  :style="dropDownStyle"
                  :options="personOptions"
                  option-label="description"
                  option-value="id"
                  placeholder="Number of persons"
                />
dropDownStyle = position:relative; top:-9.1vw; left:0.1vw; width:12vw; height:2vw; font-family:Lato; font-size:1.2vw

Comment: How do you format replies so they are readable on this site?

Comment: Try to add `!important` after each css property, like: `font-family: Lato !important;`

Comment: Added !important after each. No change.

Comment: How about `::v-global` ?

Comment: Doesn’t global mean it’s going to change across all components instead of just one that I need

Comment: There is one more way, to use `slot` for dropdown items, it should override the element.

Comment: I am new enough to view to not know exactly how to do that to a 3rd party component.

Comment: Check example from 2nd update, it use `slot` and doesn't override css classes.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, either in variable.scss, you can set default style as in main class of control:

```
.p-component, .p-inputtext {
   font-family: inherit;
}
```